# How to use MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, ios4, messageui

I am using MFMailComposeViewController in my app and the mail sending part seems to be OK.
 But when I leave the mail app, things go wrong :

```
- one toolbar (UIToolbar object) has disappeared.
- one pointer (UIImageView*) has become nil, without me doing anything for that to happen.
```

In other words the calling environment is changed although I do not want it to change.
Where could be my mistake?

Here is my code, in case someone can see something wrong :

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                    error:(NSError*)error
{
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


-(IBAction)sendAsEMail {
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposeViewController=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate=self;
[mailComposeViewController setSubject:@"Mail subject"];
[mailComposeViewController setMessageBody:@"This is for you !" isHTML:NO]; 
[mailComposeViewController addAttachmentData:
 [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[My_ViewController getDocDir] stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                 [pictureNames objectAtIndex:userItemSelected]]]
                                    mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Picture.png"];
if (mailComposeViewController) [self presentModalViewController:mailComposeViewController animated:YES];
[mailComposeViewController release];
}
```

Thanks for any piece of relevant information.

Comment: It's more likely that your errors will be in `viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidAppear:`, `viewWillDisappear:`, `viewDidDisappear:`

Comment: I see, the thing is : I do not implement viewDidAppear:, viewWillDisappear:, viewDidDisappear. In viewWillAppear: I do "myImageView=nil;myToolBar.hidden=YES;" I do not really see the problem ... unless viewWillAppear is called when I come back from doing the mail business. I will check that.

Comment: Yes the problem happens in viewWillAppear. I did not think this method would be called when finishing with MFMailComposeViewController thanks for the tip.

Comment: `viewWillAppear:` is called every time the view comes onto the screen, it doesn't matter how it was hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this link it explain in detail

1. Add framework
2. Then .h file header files
3. Then .m file the mail code

Check at [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnJLDLVJDDs).